# Find a 3 x 3 orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Find a 3x3 orthogonal matrix whose first column is $[\frac1{\sqrt{3}},{- \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}}, \frac1{\sqrt{3}}]$.

I was thinking this has to do with: ${Q}^T•Q=I_{n}$, but I still don't understand how to go about this.

Comment: I know that for it to be an orthogonal matrix, the columns form an orthogonal basis

Comment: No, they have to form an ortho*normal* basis.

Comment: You know one vector of a basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Try to *complete* the basis,using techniques you know. Now, use Gram-Schmidt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose first vector is the vector $v_1 = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right)^T$ given to you. This can be done in several ways:

1. Complete $v_1$ arbitrary to a basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and perform Gram-Schmidt to get $v_1,v_2',v_3'$. Then you can take $Q = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$.
2. Find two linearly independent vectors $v_2,v_3$ that are orthogonal to $v_1$ and perform Gram-Schmidt on them to get $v_2',v_3'$. Then you can take $Q = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$.

Let me demonstrate the second method. Since normalization is not important for orthogonality, we need to find two linearly independent vectors that are orthogonal to $(1,-1,1)^T$. Just by playing with vectors whose entries are $\pm 1$, we can get two such vectors

$$ v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

If we perform Gram-Schmidt on $(v_2,v_3)$ we get

$$ v_2' = \frac{v_2}{\| v_2 \|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \\
v_3' = \frac{v_3 - \left< v_3, v_2 \right> v_2}{\| v_3 - \left< v_3, v_2 \right> v_2 \|} = \frac{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}}{\dots} = \frac{\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}}{\| \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \|} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{10}} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{10}} \\ \frac{\sqrt{4}}{\sqrt{10}} \end{pmatrix} $$

and so we can take $Q$ to be

$$ Q = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{10}} \\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{10}} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{4}}{\sqrt{10}} \end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: Could you explain how you got $v_{2}$ and $v_{3}$

Comment: You want two vectors that are orthogonal to $(1,-1,1$). Let's denote a general such vector by $(x,y,z)$ so that it must satisfy $x \cdot 1 - y \cdot 1 + z \cdot 1 = x - y + z = 0$. Now just choose $x,y,z$ to be $\pm 1$ so that this equation is satisfied and you get two linearly independent vectors.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how you used Gram-Schmidt because I know the formula is: $v_{2}$ = ($u_{2}$•$v_{1}$/$v_{1}$•$v_{1}$)•$v_{1}$ and when I plug in the vector I get [1 1 0]

Comment: @AmR: I'm not sure what formula you use but it doesn't look correct. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process.

Comment: I used $v_{2}$ = $u_{2}$-proj($u_{2}$ on $v_{1}$)

Comment: @AmR: Did you notice you need to project $v_3$ on $v_2$ in our case, not $v_1$?

Comment: Oh, yes I see what I did. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't Q transpose(Q) = I?

Answer (score 2):

In this case we can also guess $3$ vectors without calling for Gram-Schmidt by noticing

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\text{ , }\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}\text{ are orthogonal.}$

By keeping first and third coordinate of $v_1,v_2$ equal, we were able to find an easy $v_3$.

Normalizing this gives $Q=\frac 1{\sqrt{6}}\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2} & 1 & \sqrt{3} \\ -\sqrt{2} & 2 & 0 \\ \sqrt{2} & 1 & -\sqrt{3} \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Would it be correct if I wrote?: $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \frac1{\sqrt{3}} & \frac1{\sqrt{6}} & \frac1{\sqrt{2}} \\
        {- \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}} & { \frac 2{\sqrt{6}}} & 0 \\
        \frac1{\sqrt{3}} & { \frac 1{\sqrt{6}}} & {- \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @AmR Yes, it is the same matrix, I just factored by $1/\sqrt{6}$ outside, to avoid writing many fractions. You can also swap columns 2 and 3 if you want a zero in the center. It's only an aesthetic matter.